# Is there a way to manually register a user with a py-transport server-side?

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to write some scripts to migrate my users to ejabberd, but 
the only way that's been suggested for me to register a user with a 
transport is to have them use their client and discover the service. 
Certainly there is a way, right?

Comment: Not sure I can provide an answer but, is it just the transports needing registration?  Or are you also looking for a way to get them registered in ejabberd as well as the transports?  Also, what database backend did you configure for ejabberd?

Comment: Just the transports. Everything else is taken care of -- basically I just want to register user X's AIM or yahoo or msn account with their jabber account.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go through once for each transport
   and register yourself.  Capture the
   XMPP packets.
2. Dump the transport
   registration data from your current
   system into a csv file, xml file, or
   something else you can know the
   structure.
3. Write a script
   using jabberpy, xmpppy, pyxmpp, or
   whatever, and emulate each of your
   users registering with the
   transports.

One issue is you may have to be connected to the Internet for the transports to come online.  Then you're going live with someone else's account.  If you can't get their current password data for your jabber server, set it all to a default and then migrate it back after your transport registration.